# How can I troubleshoot server overload warnings on my Raspberry Pi 4 Minecraft server using PaperMC?

Tags: server, raspberry-pi, minecraft

I opened the minecraft server using raspberrypi 4B model which has 4GB ram
I allocated 3GB to server and used the paperMC to open server.
Also I formatted to rasberrypi OS 64 bit version.

It works well, but sometimes the server connection was lost.
and this is the error message printed on the cmd of raspberrypi.

```
[21:49:07 WARN]: Can't keep up! Is the server overloaded? Running 8763ms or 175 ticks behind
[21:49:54 WARN]: Can't keep up! Is the server overloaded? Running 16587ms or 331 ticks behind
[21:51:22 WARN]: Can't keep up! Is the server overloaded? Running 5621ms or 112 ticks behind
[21:51:59 WARN]: Can't keep up! Is the server overloaded? Running 5089ms or 101 ticks behind
[21:52:39 WARN]: Can't keep up! Is the server overloaded? Running 9787ms or 195 ticks behind
[21:53:21 INFO]: [myname] lost connection: Disconnected
[21:53:31 ERROR]: --- DO NOT REPORT THIS TO PAPER - THIS IS NOT A BUG OR A CRASH  - git-Paper-538 (MC: 1.19.4) ---
[21:53:33 ERROR]: The server has not responded for 10 seconds! Creating thread dump
[21:53:37 ERROR]: ------------------------------
[21:53:41 ERROR]: Server thread dump (Look for plugins here before reporting to Paper!):
> ./start.sh: 줄 1:  1213 죽었음               java -Xms3000M -Xmx3000M -jar paper-1.19.4-538.jar
```

I can't find the problem of this.
Please help me to play minecraft with friends.@==(^o^)@

I want to reopen the server.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's best asked on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ where people may know the answer.

Comment: I don't know if put this on RaspberryPi website would be the best idea. It's not an issue only on this paltform. The warn are not important, it could appear everywhere and without plugin. You should take a look to plugins if you have. Can you provide the full log file, mostly the error part?

Comment: I don't use any plugins. It is just vanilla minecraft that i used. and It was the all part of the error part. And other log was common log just like "someone entered the server".